# NoSuchElementException when formatting number on Android, but not on Java SE

Tags: java, android, string-formatting, nan

I am porting an existing application to Android, and stumbled upon the following problem. This piece of code works perfectly fine on Java SE:

```
    String NAN_STRING = "";
    DecimalFormatSymbols SYMBOLS;
    SYMBOLS = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    SYMBOLS.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    SYMBOLS.setNaN(NAN_STRING);
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.###", SYMBOLS);

    double d = Double.NaN;

    System.out.print("x");
    System.out.print(format.format(d));
    System.out.print("y");
```

However, on Android, I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` when executing `format.format(d)`:

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at libcore.icu.NativeDecimalFormat$FieldPositionIterator.next(NativeDecimalFormat.java:564)
    at libcore.icu.NativeDecimalFormat$FieldPositionIterator.setFieldPosition(NativeDecimalFormat.java:550)
    at libcore.icu.NativeDecimalFormat$FieldPositionIterator.access$000(NativeDecimalFormat.java:507)
    at libcore.icu.NativeDecimalFormat.formatDouble(NativeDecimalFormat.java:264)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:677)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:211)
    at com.example.androidtestbed.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
```

If I replace `NAN_STRING` with e.g. `"NaN"` instead of `""`, it seems to work, but this is not the behaviour I desired. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the Android classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not the right forum for reporting Android core library bugs. code.google.com is where where you should report Android core library bugs: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59600

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I suspected there would be a bug in my code I overlooked. With such well-established core libraries, its usually the user who is wrong ;)